# Dúvida sobre condicional (if) em função

Tags: r, if

Tenho um conjunto de 300 e poucas planilhas no qual temos que criar uma função com 3 argumentos: o diretório onde estão as planilhas, a variável que será analisada e a quantidade de arquivos que se deseja analisar.

No caso em questão temos duas variáveis de interesse, a concentração de sulfato e a concentração de nitrato.

Eu consegui equacionar a função para dois parâmetros, no qual me retornará a média de sulfato e separadamente a média de nitrato.

Segue o código:

```
pollutant_sulfate<-function(directory, ID = 1:332) {
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
    data <- data.frame()
    for (i in ID) {
            data <- rbind(data, read.csv(files_list[i]))
    }
    subset_sulfate<- subset(data$sulfate, data$sulfate > 0)
    mean (subset_sulfate)
}

pollutant_nitrate<-function(directory, ID = 1:332) {
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
    data <- data.frame()
    for (i in ID) {
            data <- rbind(data, read.csv(files_list[i]))
    }
    subset_nitrate<- subset(data$nitrate, data$nitrate > 0)
    mean (subset_nitrate)
}
```

Agora o 3º argumento da função que seria a determinação de qual variável eu desejo analisar (sulfato ou nitrato) eu estou com dificuldades. Pensei na construção de um condicionante `if`. Escrevi um código que contem erros e não consigo entender qual o problema. Segue o código em questão:

```
mean_pollutant1<-function(directory, pollutant, ID=1:332){
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
    data <- data.frame()
    for (i in ID) {
        data <- rbind(data, read.csv(files_list[i]))
    }
    if (pollutant == sulfate){
        subset_sulfate<- subset(data$sulfate, data$sulfate > 0)
        mean (subset_sulfate)   
    }
    if (pollutant == nitrate){
        subset_nitrate<- subset(data$nitrate, data$nitrate > 0)
        mean (subset_nitrate)
    }
}
```

Quando eu tento chamar a função recebo msg de erro:

> mean_pollutant1("specdata", sulfate, 1:2)
>   Error in mean_pollutant1("specdata", sulfate, 1:2) : 
>     object 'sulfate' not found

Alguém pode me ajudar a contornar o problema?

Comment: acho que no if vc tem que colocar entre aspas: `if (pollutant == "sulfate")....if (pollutant == "nitrate")`e o mesmo quando for chamar a função: `mean_pollutant1("specdata", "sulfate", 1:2)`

Comment: EU acho que você ainda não criou um as variáveis `sulfate`e `nitrate`, se forem variáveis. ou como o Daniel disse, se são _strings_ coloque aspas.

Comment: Galera, problema parcialmente resolvido! Muito obrigado! Realmente eu tenho que inserir como string. Todavia, quando dou entrada na função em "nitrate" eu consigo a resposta correta. Todavia, na entrada "sulfate" que é o primeiro if a resposta da função é uma linha em branco. Não há nenhuma notificação de erro, apenas a linha de comando limpa. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: isso quer dizer que nas planilhas não tem nenhum `sulfate > 0`. a princípio o código está correto. Ou então teve algum erro de ortografia ao escrever 'sulfate'.. veja que se vc colocar `pollutant = 'x'` vc também receberá uma linha vazia

Comment: Na planilha há valores maiores que 0 para sulfato. E no caso qualquer string diferente de "nitrate" ele resulta em uma linha em branco. o.O

Comment: Isso acontece porque com qualquer string diferente a função não entra em nenhum dos if's e então retorna vazio. será que na planilha não tem um espaço a mais no nome da coluna, ou algo do tipo? Pq aparentemente o problema é que não está entrando em nenhum if quando vc usa a string "sulfate".

Comment: Gente, um amigo me ajudou. Não sei responder o porque do motivo, mas trocamos o segundo if por um else if e deu certo! Sabe Deus porque dois if's seguidos estavam resultando em erro! Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram!

Comment: @DanielFalbel acho que você poderia colocar como resposta seu primeiro comentário. José Ferraz, sempre é interessante colocar um pequeno exemplo da base de dados para reproduzirmos o seu erro. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/825#825

Answer (score 3):

O problema do seu código é que você está fazendo uma comparação com objetos que não existem.

Em `if (pollutant == sulfate)`, o objeto `sulfate` não existe. Você pode resolver o problema de duas maneiras:

1. Antes do `if`criar o obejto, atribuindo o valor de uma string, ou seja, colocar antes do `if` um `sulfate <- 'sulfate'`
2. Comparar direto com a string `'sulfate'`, `if (pollutant == 'sulfate')`.

Isso você deve fazer para os dois `if`'s.

O outro problema do seu código é que está faltando um `return`. No `R`, é possível retornar valores de uma função sem usar o `return`, mas apenas se o valor retornado for o último comando da função.

No seu caso, o último comando da função é

```
if (pollutant == 'nitrate'){
    subset_nitrate<- subset(data$nitrate, data$nitrate > 0)
    mean (subset_nitrate)
}
```

Por isso qualquer string diferente de `'nitrate'` retornará `NULL`. Para resolver isso basta colocar um `return()` em cada if. Portanto, a função correta seria:

```
mean_pollutant1<-function(directory, pollutant, ID=1:332){
    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
    data <- data.frame()
    for (i in ID) {
        data <- rbind(data, read.csv(files_list[i]))
    }
    if (pollutant == 'sulfate'){
        subset_sulfate<- subset(data$sulfate, data$sulfate > 0)
        return(mean(subset_sulfate))
    }
    if (pollutant == 'nitrate'){
        subset_nitrate<- subset(data$nitrate, data$nitrate > 0)
        return(mean (subset_nitrate))
    }
}
```

Claro que existem outras saídas para evitar ter que usar o `return`, mas essa é a que menos modifica o seu código original.